# Modelling issue with rcpsp and boolean expressions

Tags: modeling, constraint-programming, or-tools, c++, cp-sat

I'm trying to solve an RCPSPDc problem in OR-Tools with CP-SAT solver.

In my RCPSPDc model (with discount rate) i want to set this objective:
$$\max_{s}\sum_{j\in J}\text{profit}_{j}\cdot \frac{1}{(1+\alpha)^{s_{j}}}$$
$s$ is my vector of variables, each element saves the value where the job $j\in J$ begins, i'm modeling this as an interval variable. $\alpha$ is the discount rate. 
Actually, I can't use float values in the objective and can't power values to an IntVar (OR-Tools don't permit), so I'm following a similar approach to the model with binary variable, but using the same variable $s$, and rounding the values.

I want to create a vector $\rm obj$ of size $N_{jobs}\cdot t_\max$ (number of jobs and horizon) and save as `IntVar` the precomputed expression $\textbf{w}$ of the sum with a boolean expression: `s[j]==t`, so it can be activated only in that case.

I did this:

```
 std::vector<IntVar> obj_final(nbTasks*tmax);
    for (int j = 0; j < nbTasks; ++j)
    {
        for (int t = 0; i < tmax; ++t)
        {
            const IntVar expr = cp_model.NewIntVar(Domain(-1000000000000000000,10000000000000000));
            const BoolVar bl = cp_model.NewBoolVar();
            cp_model.AddEquality(bl, starts[j]==actual_t);
            cp_model.AddEquality(round(w[j][i],expr).OnlyEnforceIf(bl);
            obj_final.push_back(expr);
        }
    }
```

but obviously it doesn't work because of the constraint of `starts[j]==t` (start of the interval variable $j$).

I tried to enforce it in that way:

`cp_model.AddEquality(round(w[j][i],expr).OnlyEnforceIf(s[j]==t);`

but `OnlyEnforceIf` takes only `BoolVars` and not bool.

How can I assign a value to a `BoolVar` as we do with `IntVar -> cp_model.NewConstant()`?

How can I make it to finally set as an objective the sum of all the elements in the vector that I created?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: For a given `j`, why don't you precompute `[profit_j * 1/(1 + alpha)^x for x in range(0, horizon)]`. Then just use `model.AddElement(profit_var[j], precomputed_profit_array, start_j)`.

Comment: sounds good but what exactly does AddElement, what is an element constraint?

Comment: https://books.google.es/books?id=8l9qCQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA458&ots=2PDHimj_oH&dq=cp%20element%20constraint&pg=PA188#v=onepage&q&f=false and https://google.github.io/or-tools/cpp_sat/classoperations__research_1_1sat_1_1CpModelBuilder.html#ab58d2ffae5a0a7e7b0111bf6f465a018